# How to force authorization in a React app hosted as an ASP.NET Core 6 web application?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-authorization

I have created a new ASP.NET Core 6 web application with a frontend in React (I used the "ASP.NET Core with React.js" template). I want to implement SSO into it (using a custom company SSO for it; company policy), but I struggle with a problem when I try to force authentication.

The idea is to always be authenticated. The problem is, I don't know how, and what I tried did not work (or did not work as I expected it to work).

As part of the configuration I have:

```
.AddSession()
.AddAuthorization()
.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => {
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
```

And later on:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.ShouldAuthenticateNow())
        await context.ChallengeAsync();

    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self';");
    await next();
});
```

Where `ShouldAuthenticateNow()` is an extension method with the following content:

```
public static bool ShouldAuthenticateNow(this HttpContext context)
    => context.User == null
    || context.User.Identity == null
    || !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

I know I can achieve that by adding `RequireAuthorization()` in the `Program.cs` (as we know, in .NET 6 there is no startup anymore):

```
app
   .MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
   .RequireAuthorization();
```

The problem is, it is not working. Or at least, it is not working for the React front end that is loaded or any view in it, as there are no controllers (I was surprised myself).

When I added a sample controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [Route("account")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And entered that route - it redirected me to the SSO. But it's not working for the React part.

How can I make .NET Authorization work also on React app's view?

Comment: Which SSO your company is using? Azure AD  or ADFS or some identity server?

Comment: The SSO works correctly for multiple projects. I don't think many of them were made in .NET 6, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

"ASP.NET Core with React.js" just pretend to be one project ,but they are actually seperate react front-end and net core webapi back-end.  They can run independently which means:
Any configuration in the net core will only affect on the back-end api endpoint. 
The react part has its own javascript configuration to protect its every component on authentication.

The configuration differs depending on what SSO is being used.
Such as Azure AD :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react